# In Sitecore Forms Extensions for 9.1, can I get special characters to work?

Tags: exm, sitecore-forms

Sitecore Forms Extensions version 2.2.1 in Sitecore 9.1.1

Our sent out email has decoded special characters in the input text fields, like 'ö' is in mail '&#246 ;'

Anyone know how I can get past this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a known issue that Sitecore Support helped clear up.

It was about html encoding for tokens in plain text messages.

Link to Sitecore support github: https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.296165

There is some manual work to make it work with Sitecore 9.1.1 in my case since it was built for 9.0.